# Pandas Data Normalization is giving weird output Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow

I have tried to create a train and test dataset and have found that the output after training what a weird graph which was not expected.

The issue I came across is because of the use of the dataset normalization. The output of the training dataset and testing dataset is somewhat weird.

Have a look at the code:

```
dataset_train = pd.read_csv('TrainEURUSD.csv',usecols=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])
dataset_train.head(10)
```

Output:

```
0   1.16833 1.16835 1.16823 1.16831 1.16833 66.101695   84.903097   0.000164    -6.314161e-06   84.903097   1.168795    1.168415    1.168034
1   1.16827 1.16835 1.16827 1.16833 1.16842 88.607595   90.104971   0.000150    -9.244212e-07   90.104971   1.168840    1.168437    1.168033
2   1.16842 1.16843 1.16841 1.16842 1.16842 100.000000  75.569106   0.000164    3.503926e-06    75.569106   1.168882    1.168458    1.168034
3   1.16833 1.16845 1.16823 1.16842 1.16833 81.707317   51.326681   0.000156    -1.376676e-05   51.326681   1.168885    1.168462    1.168038
4   1.16831 1.16835 1.16831 1.16833 1.16825 45.000000   28.316261   0.000162    -4.390005e-05   28.316261   1.168889    1.168466    1.168042
5   1.16813 1.16825 1.16813 1.16825 1.16811 27.272727   27.675236   0.000168    -6.926663e-05   27.675236   1.168890    1.168471    1.168052
6   1.16828 1.16828 1.16811 1.16811 1.16828 12.676056   28.729254   0.000159    -8.585350e-05   28.729254   1.168898    1.168488    1.168078
7   1.16824 1.16832 1.16814 1.16828 1.16823 43.076923   35.059457   0.000158    -6.783461e-05   35.059457   1.168882    1.168511    1.168139
8   1.16840 1.16840 1.16820 1.16823 1.16840 30.434783   24.246582   0.000157    -7.448502e-05   24.246582   1.168878    1.168521    1.168165
9   1.16821 1.16840 1.16821 1.16840 1.16821 31.666667   18.546099   0.000166    -6.451244e-05   18.546099   1.168868    1.168538    1.168207
```

Next:

```
dataset_test = pd.read_csv('Test_EURUSD.csv',usecols=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])
dataset_test.head(10)
```

Output:

```
0   1.16610 1.16615 1.16601 1.16603 1.16610 25.000000   53.309179   0.000080    -0.000027   53.309179   1.166276    1.166168    1.166061
1   1.16623 1.16623 1.16610 1.16610 1.16623 56.666667   63.494364   0.000074    -0.000010   63.494364   1.166274    1.166180    1.166086
2   1.16617 1.16624 1.16617 1.16623 1.16618 78.260870   52.012882   0.000071    0.000003    52.012882   1.166290    1.166190    1.166090
3   1.16613 1.16618 1.16612 1.16618 1.16613 55.555556   34.259259   0.000068    -0.000009   34.259259   1.166301    1.166193    1.166085
4   1.16615 1.16615 1.16612 1.16613 1.16615 22.222222   23.518519   0.000067    -0.000018   23.518519   1.166312    1.166198    1.166084
5   1.16613 1.16615 1.16613 1.16615 1.16612 25.000000   24.005848   0.000069    -0.000017   24.005848   1.166334    1.166208    1.166083
6   1.16617 1.16621 1.16612 1.16612 1.16617 23.333333   25.672515   0.000073    -0.000019   25.672515   1.166351    1.166217    1.166084
7   1.16618 1.16626 1.16615 1.16617 1.16618 23.684211   35.355054   0.000069    -0.000013   35.355054   1.166388    1.166233    1.166078
8   1.16614 1.16619 1.16614 1.16618 1.16614 30.000000   53.956044   0.000074    -0.000014   53.956044   1.166420    1.166246    1.166072
9   1.16618 1.16618 1.16609 1.16614 1.16618 52.380952   68.465848   0.000071    -0.000017   68.465848   1.166447    1.166259    1.166070
```

Then I normalized the datasets, using the following:

```
datasetTrain = (dataset_train - dataset_train.mean()) / (dataset_train.max() - dataset_train.min())
datasetTrain.head(10)
```

Output:

```
0   0.019674    0.017293    0.019989    0.019084    0.019678    0.160252    0.348290    -0.010598   -0.002514   0.348290    0.020240    0.023543    0.025458
1   0.017889    0.017293    0.021206    0.019679    0.022357    0.385311    0.400309    -0.019556   -0.000335   0.400309    0.021616    0.024238    0.025413
2   0.022352    0.019660    0.025462    0.022357    0.022357    0.499235    0.254950    -0.010598   0.001454    0.254950    0.022881    0.024918    0.025449
3   0.019674    0.020251    0.019989    0.022357    0.019678    0.316308    0.012526    -0.015313   -0.005526   0.012526    0.022982    0.025028    0.025563
4   0.019079    0.017293    0.022422    0.019679    0.017297    -0.050765   -0.217578   -0.011541   -0.017706   -0.217578   0.023099    0.025154    0.025691
5   0.013723    0.014336    0.016949    0.017298    0.013131    -0.228038   -0.223988   -0.007769   -0.027959   -0.223988   0.023134    0.025328    0.025996
6   0.018186    0.015223    0.016341    0.013131    0.018190    -0.374004   -0.213448   -0.013899   -0.034664   -0.213448   0.023353    0.025865    0.026824
7   0.016996    0.016406    0.017253    0.018191    0.016702    -0.069996   -0.150146   -0.014370   -0.027381   -0.150146   0.022889    0.026576    0.028693
8   0.021756    0.018772    0.019077    0.016703    0.021761    -0.196417   -0.258275   -0.014842   -0.030069   -0.258275   0.022761    0.026923    0.029506
9   0.016103    0.018772    0.019381    0.021762    0.016107    -0.184098   -0.315280   -0.008712   -0.026038   -0.315280   0.022459    0.027429    0.030806
```

And for the test dataset:

```
datasetTest = (dataset_test - dataset_test.mean()) / (dataset_test.max() - dataset_test.min())
datasetTest.head(10)
```

Output:

```
0   -0.148985   -0.151914   -0.150167   -0.152497   -0.148978   -0.248599   0.034471    -0.083573   -0.022027   0.034471    -0.167361   -0.152037   -0.135121
1   -0.142436   -0.147849   -0.145610   -0.148971   -0.142429   0.068068    0.136323    -0.090135   -0.007864   0.136323    -0.167459   -0.151432   -0.133844
2   -0.145459   -0.147341   -0.142066   -0.142422   -0.144947   0.284010    0.021508    -0.094237   0.002898    0.021508    -0.166600   -0.150906   -0.133647
3   -0.147474   -0.150390   -0.144598   -0.144941   -0.147466   0.056957    -0.156028   -0.097518   -0.007581   -0.156028   -0.166023   -0.150748   -0.133897
4   -0.146466   -0.151914   -0.144598   -0.147460   -0.146459   -0.276377   -0.263436   -0.098339   -0.014414   -0.263436   -0.165428   -0.150485   -0.133959
5   -0.147474   -0.151914   -0.144091   -0.146452   -0.147970   -0.248599   -0.258562   -0.095878   -0.013806   -0.258562   -0.164281   -0.149933   -0.133990
6   -0.145459   -0.148866   -0.144598   -0.147963   -0.145451   -0.265266   -0.241896   -0.091776   -0.015730   -0.241896   -0.163404   -0.149459   -0.133914
7   -0.144955   -0.146325   -0.143079   -0.145445   -0.144947   -0.261757   -0.145070   -0.095878   -0.010578   -0.145070   -0.161441   -0.148644   -0.134220
8   -0.146970   -0.149882   -0.143585   -0.144941   -0.146963   -0.198599   0.040939    -0.090956   -0.011433   0.040939    -0.159733   -0.147960   -0.134537
9   -0.144955   -0.150390   -0.146117   -0.146956   -0.144947   0.025211    0.186038    -0.093417   -0.014001   0.186038    -0.158295   -0.147302   -0.134643
```

As one can see the difference between the train dataset and test dataset normalized, the values corresponding to the columns are reverse in sign. That is the value is positive in the train dataset column whereas in test is negative.

Here are the link for the [test](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/2c468679fa66c04c08a0ca624ca92d8f) and [train](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/726c04657816fc9a5006fc7c70df1e4e) dataset.

Kindly, suggest me what I have missed. Or am I making some mistake.

Comment: I have played around with the dataset and i think it is a common behavior. Not all the values in the set are negative which suggests that most of the values are lesser in value than mean. If you take a look in  datasetTrain normalization, you can find negative values as well. You can print out mean to verify this. Cheers!

Comment: One more thing, the mean is being calculated based on columns rather than rows. (Shouldn't be a problem in most of the cases. Just pointing it out)

Comment: Thank you. your suggestions are valuable to me. I learn many new things here on Stackoverflow from people who are supportive like you.